# Solving $\tan^{-1}x > \cot^{-1}x$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, inverse-function

I am doing problems in Inverse Trigonometric Functions. I faced some issues while solving Inverse Trigonometric Inequalities. I have mentioned the question, the solution given in my book and the way in which I attempted the problem in the image below.
[image]

As you could see, clearly the book answer does not match with mine. I tried my best to identify the mistake in my procedure, but I was unable to find any errors. **Kindly tell where I have went wrong**. I am sure I have gone wrong since I solved the question graphically and attained the result given in my book.

Comment: Extremely sorry for attaching an image, as I didn't understand how to type stuff in MathJax.

Comment: Since you took the tangent on both sides, you have to check for extraneous solutions. Substituting $x=-1$ demonstrates that the inequality is not true, so you have to exclude that whole interval.

Comment: @TobyMak Thank you for your response. Actually x= -1 is not included in my solution set since it is an open interval not closed. But, anyway, I realised the place I made an error. Thanks a lot for spending your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies in$$\arctan(x)>\pi+\arctan\left(\frac1x\right)\implies x>\tan\left(\pi+\arctan\left(\frac1x\right)\right).$$The tangent function is *not* a strictly increasing function, although its restriction to intervals of the form $\left(k\pi-\frac\pi2,k\pi+\frac\pi2\right)$ is.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values

$$\dfrac\pi2>\tan^{-1}x,\cot^{-1}x>0$$

We must have $$\dfrac\pi2>\tan^{-1}x>\cot^{-1}x>0$$

$\implies x>0$